# Game Center In SpriteKit Not Dismissing Leader Board

Tags: ios, game-center, sprite-kit

After a lot of searching on here I finally found a way for Game Center to display in SpriteKit but now I can't get the `leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish` method to call. I use this code in a different app and it works fine but for some reason with the code being modified for SpriteKit its just not working. Thank you in advance!

Here is a sample of my code:

```
- (void)showGameCenterButtonPressed:(id)sender {
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You must enable Game Center!"
                                                          message:@"Sign in through the Game Center app to enable all features"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
    } else {
        GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        if (leaderboardViewController != NULL)
        {

            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: leaderboardViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

}
}

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"in leaderboardControllerDidFinish");
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question... 
I just took the code straight from Apple

```
- (void)showGameCenterButtonPressed:(id)sender {
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You must enable Game Center!"
                                                          message:@"Sign in through the Game Center app to enable all features"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
    } else {
        GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {
            gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)gameCenterViewController {

UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}