# Game Center "Done" button issue?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The "Done" button in Game Center will not dismiss the controller. My code to dismiss the view controller is exactly the same everywhere I look. I've looked at similar questions on here but no luck. Can anyone help me?

GameScene.Swift (This serves as my start menu )

```
class GameScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {


var startBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play button")
var title = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:  "AvenirNext-UltraLight")
var leaderboardButtonImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "leaderboard button")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)

    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    startBtn.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - 100, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    startBtn.size = CGSize(width: 140, height: 55)
    self.addChild(startBtn)

    leaderboardButtonImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 100, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    leaderboardButtonImage.size = CGSize(width: 140, height: 55)
    self.addChild(leaderboardButtonImage)

}





func showLeaderboard() {

    let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    let gc = GKGameCenterViewController()

    gc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
    gc.leaderboardIdentifier = "I removed this part"
    vc!.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)



}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {

    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}




override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches ) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if (startBtn.containsPoint(location)) {

            self.view?.presentScene(GamePlayScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))
            GamePlayScene().scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            startBtn.removeFromParent()
            title.removeFromParent()
            leaderboardButtonImage.removeFromParent()

        }

        if (leaderboardButtonImage.containsPoint(location)) {

            showLeaderboard()

        }

    }

}



}
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the obj-c answer?

Comment: @UlyssesR Sorry for the late reply. This is one that I was using for reference to fix the "Done" button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308044/game-center-in-spritekit-not-dismissing-leader-board        I can't figure out why the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In my func showLeaderboard(), I had to add the line **gc.gameCenterDelegate = self** which made the "Done" button work.

I hope other people who have this same problem see this potential fix.

```
func showLeaderboard() {

let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
let gc = GKGameCenterViewController()

gc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
gc.leaderboardIdentifier = "I removed this part"
vc!.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```